# Do I really need a huge plist file to replicate this cron job?

Tags: macos, launchd, cron

I am looking to create a launchd job that will execute Monday through Friday at 7:32am, 8:32am, and 2pm. Do I *really* need a plist that has an array of 15 `<dict>` elements for every combination of Weekday + Hour:Minute? Is there no shorthand to repeat like cron syntax has? Haven't found any examples or docs that say so, I just don't believe this is preferable over a simple dual crontab like

`32 7,8 * * 1-5 script >> /tmp/logfile`

and

`0 14 * * 1-5 script >> /tmp/logfile`

Which, on Yosemite 10.10.5, no longer seems to run like it used to. Is it turned off somehow?

This equivalent in plist launchd format is just huge:

```
<key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
  <array>
    <!-- M-F 7:32am -->
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>7</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>2</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>7</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>3</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>7</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>7</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>5</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>7</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <!-- M-F 8:32am -->
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>8</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>2</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>8</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>3</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>8</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>8</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>5</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>8</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>32</integer>
    </dict>
    <!-- M-F 2:00p -->
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>1</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>14</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>2</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>14</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>3</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>14</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>4</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>14</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>Weekday</key>
      <integer>5</integer>
      <key>Hour</key>
      <integer>14</integer>
      <key>Minute</key>
      <integer>00</integer>
    </dict>
  </array>
```

Comment: The joy of XML (worsened by Apple's use of key/value pairs). But cron should still work in 10.10, please ask a new question if you want help in solving any problem you might have there.

Comment: at least, you can write a script which will generate these plists